# How to use existing classes as datacontract in wcf?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

We are planning to upgrade our Windows service to WCF service, I know this is nothing to do with the question. There are hundreds of classes are defined in several dlls.

I am doing some R&D to pass the existing classes objects shown in below code over WCF service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    UserSession LoginUser(User user);
}
```

"UserSession" and "User" classes used in above code are predefined normal classes in a assembly. As these classes are not defined as 'DataContract' the service is not able serialize them.

I could not afford to redefine those classes as 'DataContract'.
Is there any way to use existing classes as 'DataContract' to communicate smoothly between client and server.

Note - I have gone through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx), It's long way to follow for hundreds of classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `[DataContract]` attribute is *optional* as WCF 3.5.  If you don't specify it, WCF will attempt to use `DataContractSerializer` by default (unless you change that).  What have you observed that indicates to you that its not being serialized?  Note that the only thing that will be serialized is the data - the methods and constructors will not be serialized and will not be known by the client unless the assemblies they are in are shared.  This is by design to keep things SOA.  Can you post an example of one of the classes?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around for solutions that will allow you to send an entire class through as a DataContract and it just doesn't seem to exist.
Best advice I can give is to retrieve the data in these classes using a reader and to then send the data through via a DataContract. But I take it that's exactly what you don't want to have to do.